# Detect Android device movement on Plain Surface

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am creating a project in Android.
This have pre-requirement is : **Play video By moving Android device.**

I have implemented Accelerometer Sensor, but if I move device on Plain surface and move device Up, Down, Left or Right, then No Event is called. It is only detects when device rotates in any direction.

Is it possible **to detect moving device on plain surface??**

Thanks in Advance.